# Linq implicity typed range variable

Tags: c#

With Linq, the range variable (e) can be implicitly typed from the array/collection (emps) it is coming from, but a foreach statement cannot do the same thing without the var keyword, or a type. Why is this?

In ex1 the compiler knows e is of type Employee, without giving a var keyword or anything. Why can't the foreach loop in ex2 do the same thing, you have to provide the type (whether its var or some type).

ex1.

```
    Employee[] emps = {new Employee ( 1, "Daniel", "Cooley", 7, 57.98M };

    public void SortByLastname()
    {
      var sortedByLastname =
            from e in emps
            orderby e.LastName
            select e.FirstName;
    }
```

ex2.

```
        foreach (Employee empl in emps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employee " + empl);
        }
```

This may be over analyzing but i'm trying to get to the bottom of why this is the case.

The answer may very well be Linq query syntax is set up to auto deduce the type of the range variable and the foreach statment is not. Can someone help explain why this is?

Comment: I don't believe ex1 is correct - it won't compile. Don't you mean Employee[] emps = new[] { new Employee(...) };...and in your second example...foreach should have no problem inferring the T in a T[] or any IEnumerable<T>...so I'm not sure I understand the issue you're describing.

Comment: Sorry first post here so getting used to how site works. Yea the second dexample is not intened to be related to the first my bad should have just put the array in the foreach instead of the linq result.

Comment: I updated your code to reflect that, and my answer :)

Comment: You don't need to specify the type of the range variable in a foreach loop, because you can use the `var` keyword e.g. `foreach (var empl in emps)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you do not need to list the type is because this is being broken down (basically) extension methods. You should be able to rewrite ex2 as:

```
emps.ForEach(empl=>Console.WriteLine("Employee " + empl);
```

Notice that you do not need to explicitly say the type as it is inferred from `emps`

So ex1 will break down to:

```
emps.OrderBy(e=>e.LastName).Select(e=>e.FirstName);
```

For a much fuller understanding of this and more, I really suggest buying Jon Skeets book [C# In Depth  Second Edition](http://manning.com/skeet2/)

Comment: wow quick response :) I'm coming here more often. So this is really an issue of how the linq code works. Whatever code behind that is powering linq is able to deduce this (like an invisible var that is always there) while the foreach statement is not? Is that correct? does it have to do with IEnumberable being the interface of the linq, while i've read that is is not actually the interface of the foreach?  Thankyou for the help.

Comment: Kind of. I suggest reading up on extension methods and generics and then how the two interact in type inference. Basically, in my example, emps.OrderBy... is really running a static method that passes emps as the first parameter. Which is then used to figure out the rest of the types. This can get to be a really broad subject to explain here, so I would highly suggest to further understand this to go and get the book I suggested...at bare minimum some google searches on the topics I mentioned

Comment: Ok thanks, so in lamens the linq syntax is using the extension methods on the array object. While the foreach is unaware of the object so it needs the type. Am I far off base? lol

Comment: Possibly over simplified, but it is a good start at understanding it. :)

Comment: haha well thanks again I'll be sure to annoy some people at work with this one.

Comment: I don't think this is really the reason. Why couldn't the compiler translate `from var e in emps select e` into `emps.Select(e => e)`? Also note what actually currently happens when you do specify the type in `from`: a call to `Cast()` is made, it's not translated as `Select((SomeType e) => e)` or something like that.

Answer (score 15):

UPDATE: [This question was the subject of my blog on June 25th, 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/06/25/foolish-consistency-is-foolish.aspx). Thanks for the great question!

---

> With Linq, the range variable can be implicitly typed from the collection it is coming from, but a foreach statement cannot do the same thing without the var keyword.

That is correct.

> Why is this?

I never know how to answer "why" questions. So I'll pretend you asked a different question:

> There are two distinct ways that a named variable may be implicitly typed. A named local variable, for loop variable, foreach loop variable, or using statement variable may be implicitly typed by substituting "var" for its explicit type. A lambda parameter or query range variable may be implicitly typed by omitting its type altogether.

Correct.

> That is an inconsistency. A basic design principle is that inconsistency is to be avoided because it is confusing; the user naturally assumes that an inconsistency conveys meaning. Could these features have been made consistent?

Indeed, there are two ways they could have been made consistent. The first is to require "var" everywhere, so that you would say:

```
Func<double, double> f = (var x)=>Math.Sin(x);
var query = from var customer in customers
            join var order in orders on customer.Id equals ...
```

All design is a series of compromises. This meets the consistency test but now feels clunky and verbose.

The second is to eliminate "var" everywhere, so that you would say:

```
x = 12; // Same as "int x = 12;"
using(file = ...) ... 
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) ...
foreach(c in customers) ...
```

In the first three cases we have now inadvertently added the feature of "implicitly declared locals" rather than "implicitly typed locals". It seems odd and non-C#-like to have a new local variable declared just because you assigned something to a name that was not previously used.  This is the sort of feature we'd expect in a language like JScript or VBScript, not C#.

However, in the foreach block it is clear from the context that a local variable is being introduced. We could eliminate "var" here without causing too much confusion, because the "in" is not mistaken for an assignment.

OK, so let's sum up our possible features:

- Feature 1: require var everywhere.
- Feature 2: require var nowhere.
- Feature 3: require var on locals, for loops and usings but not foreach loops, lambdas or range variables
- Feature 4: require var on locals, for loops using and foreach, but not lambdas or range variables

The first two have the benefits of consistency, but consistency is only one factor. The first one is clunky. The second one is too dynamic and confusing. The third and fourth ones seem like plausible compromises, though they are not consistent.

The question then is: is the foreach loop variable more like a *local variable* or more like a *lambda parameter*? Clearly it is more like a local variable; in fact, the foreach loop is *specified* as a rewrite in which the loop variable becomes a local variable. For consistency with the "for" loop, and consistency with the C# 1.0 and C# 2.0 usage of the foreach loop, which required a type of some kind, we choose option four as superior to option three.

I hope that answers your question. If not, then ask a whole lot more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'empl' is a string in the 2nd example, because the select clause of the LINQ statement says e.FirstName.  If you want it to include the employee list, use the following:

```
var sortedByLastname =
  from e in emps
  select e
  orderby e.LastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with language construct rather than variable type inferring. The reason why the foreach-loop can't do the same without the var-keyword is because `foreach(var empl in list)` and `foreach(empl in list)` means to different things (I'm not even sure the second one is legal). The first one allocates a new variable, whereas the second one (if legal) would use an already existing variable (that of cause would have to be typed correctly). However, the for in LINQ construct is made in such a way that when you do `for e in list` e is created as a variable.